# xamarin forms - how to open sms application with prefilled sms message

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using the following to open the SMS application cross platform

Device.OpenUri(new Uri(String.Format("sms:{0}", "")));

How can I prefill the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look at the [Messaging plugin](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Messaging) that is available for this.

It exposes these methods;

```
public interface ISmsTask
{
    bool CanSendSms { get; }
    bool CanSendSmsInBackground { get; }
    void SendSms(string recipient, string message);
    void SendSmsInBackground(string recipient, string message);
}
```

For more detail [read here](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Messaging/Details.md).

With this you can determine if the device can send a SMS and you can compose one to a certain recipient with a message already in the body.

Using an URL you should be able to do so with `Device.OpenUri(new Uri("sms:+00101010101&body=YourTextHere"));`. Android is more strict on the URI format, use `?body=YourTextHere`, this should work for iOS as well.

Comment: thanks. it worked for IOS. it does not work for Android though.

Comment: Try replacing the & with a ? In the url

Comment: thanks. it works. so the final solution would be:
if(Device.RuntimePlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS.ToString())
            {
                Device.OpenUri(new Uri(String.Format("sms:{0}&body={1}", "", smsContent)));
            }
            else if(Device.RuntimePlatform == TargetPlatform.Android.ToString())
            {
                Device.OpenUri(new Uri(String.Format("sms:{0}?body={1}", "", smsContent)));
            }

Comment: Did you try the question mark version on iOS as well? It _should_ work for iOS as well, so then you do not need the if. Glad it worked out! Please accept as an answer if it helped you. I'll update it a bit.